# AngularJS binding service variable to controller

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, service, binding

I am a Angular noob and having problems with binding a variable from one of my services to one of my controllers. I have read at least a dozen posts on the subject and nothing seems to be working for me.

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('TeamController', ['$scope', '$modal', 'teamService', function ($scope, $modal, teamService) {
    $scope.teamService = teamService;
    $scope.selectedTeam = null;



    $scope.selectTeam = function(teamId){
        $scope.selectedTeam = teamService.getTeam(teamId, $scope.login.loginId);
    };

}]);
```

Here is the service:

```
angular.module('teamService', [])
.service('teamService', function($http, $q){
    this.selectedTeam = {teamId:-1, teamName:"Select a team", teamLocationName:"", teamDescription:"", teamManaged:false};
    this.userTeams = [];

    this.getTeam = function(teamId, loginId) {
        var postData = {teamId: teamId, loginId: loginId};
        var promise = $http({
            url: "/url-for-getting-team",
            method: "POST",
            data: postData
        });
        promise.success(function (data) {
            if (data.status === "success") {
                this.selectedTeam = data.response;
                return data.response;
            }
        });
        promise.error(function () { //TODO handle getTeam errors
            return {};
        });
    };


    this.getSelectedTeam = function(){
      return this.selectedTeam;
    };

 });
```

And here is the template:

```
<div class="jumbotron main-jumbo" ng-controller="TeamController">
    <h1>{{selectedTeam.teamName}}</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried binding to the getSelectedTeam function and the service variable itself. Do I need to set up a $watch function in the controller? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried turning my service into a factory, which still did not help me, so then I looked at a provider that was properly working that I had already written in the application. I converted my "teamService" into a provider and finally worked like a charm. Thanks for the contributions guys.

Code from my new provider:

```
angular.module('teamService', [])
.provider('teamService', function () {
    var errorState = 'error',
        logoutState = 'home';

    this.$get = function ($rootScope, $http, $q, $state) {

        /**
         * Low-level, private functions.
         */


        /**
         * High level, public methods
         */
        var wrappedService = {
            /**
             * Public properties
             */
            selectedTeam: {teamName:"Select a team"},
            userTeams : null,
            createTeam: function(loginId, name, description, locationName, managed){
                var postData = {loginId:loginId, teamName:name, teamDescription:description, teamLocationName:locationName, teamManaged:managed};
                var promise = $http({
                    url: "/create-team-url",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: postData
                });

                return promise;
            },

            getTeam: function(teamId, loginId) {
                var postData = {teamId: teamId, loginId: loginId};
                var promise = $http({
                    url: "/get-team-url",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: postData
                });

                promise.success(function (data) {
                    if (data.status === "success") {
                        wrappedService.selectedTeam = data.response;
                    }
                });
                promise.error(function () { //TODO handle getTeam errors
                    wrappedService.selectedTeam = {};
                });
            },

            getUserTeams:  function(loginId) {
                var postData = {loginId: loginId};
                var promise = $http({
                    url: "/team-list-url",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: postData
                });
                return promise;
            },

            joinTeam:  function(teamId, loginId){
                var postData = {teamId:teamId, loginId:loginId};
                var promise =$http({
                    url: "/join-team-url",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: postData
                });
                return promise;
            },

            getSelectedTeam: function(){
                return wrappedService.selectedTeam;
            }
        };

        return wrappedService;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in my edit. I converted my service into a provider and all the changes seem to propagate to the view with no issues. I need to further analyze the difference between the factory, service, and provider in order to gain a higher understanding of what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the code is the way that promises are used.  You can either correct that within the service, or handle it in the controller.  As an example of the latter, you can re-write the above as:

Controller Code:

```
app.controller('TeamController', ['$scope', '$modal', 'teamService', function ($scope, $modal, teamService) {
    $scope.teamService = teamService;
    $scope.selectedTeam = null;

    $scope.selectTeam = function(teamId){
        teamService.getTeam(teamId, $scope.login.loginId).then(
            function(result){
                $scope.selectedTeam = result.data;
            },
            function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    };

}]);
```

Service code:

```
angular.module('teamService', [])
.service('teamService', function($http, $q){
    this.selectedTeam = {teamId:-1, teamName:"Select a team", teamLocationName:"", teamDescription:"", teamManaged:false};
    this.userTeams = [];

    this.getTeam = function(teamId, loginId) {
        var postData = {teamId: teamId, loginId: loginId};
        return $http({
            url: "/url-for-getting-team",
            method: "POST",
            data: postData
        });
    };


    this.getSelectedTeam = function(){
      return this.selectedTeam;
    };

 });
```

You can also handle this in the service itself, but it requires a little more code.  The key thing is that the `getTeam` call is asynchronous and needs to be handled using proper promise constructs.

Comment: I was not able to get this work. I think that the problem is that the changes are not being detected on the view.